# Collapsed row expanding just for a brief moment, then disappearing again

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been experimenting with HTML tables and collapsible rows, because I need a way to display more info about a row in a table after the click event.

What I did so far is

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="clickable" id="row3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#innerRow3" aria-expanded="false">
            <td class="text-center"><i id = "step3" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td>Header!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse out" id="innerRow3">
            <td>Test!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I'm seeing when I click the row with id `row3`, `innerRow3` expands for a brief moment, to disappear not even a second after it has been shown.

What I'm using is JQuery 3.2.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.7 to achieve this.

Edit: as suggested by user @charlietfl, here is a verifiable example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/r7mRgNzpvpSi5jo6bANW?p=preview

Comment: [Works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IA2b4vgBhpzzh7fpPOhG?p=preview). Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Edited question, I provided a link to a verifiable plunker. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Seems that changing Bootstrap4.0 CSS to Bootstrap 3.3.7 (same version as JS file) fixed the problem

Comment: Yes...noticed that also

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the plunker provided in this question, I had Bootstrap 4.0.0 CSS and Bootstrap 3.3.7 JS file, this probably lead to an inconsistence which caused the bug.

Switching to Bootstrap 3.3.7 CSS fixed the issue!